# Can not center div inside another div

Tags: css, html, center

I've used the search function and it just will not `center` as I cannot make sense of some suggestions and those I can do not work. Google leaves me no results either.

I want to use 1 div as a 'background as such' so that the first `150px` of the screen down are blue.

Then I want the logo in a `centered` box `950px` wide by `150px` down.

The 'logo div' (I've called it `headercontent`) needs to be 'on top' of the `headerbackgroundblue` div, which I have managed.

However it will not center the box within that div (`950px` wide centered will store all content so that it looks good on all screens, however the blue is `1920px` wide to make the website look better on larger resolutions.

**CSS**

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.headercontent {
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    height: 150px;
    width: 950px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.bluebackgroundtop {
    height: 150px;
    width: 1920px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: #3c56a6;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Kleenzone - Commercial Cleaning Services</title>
        <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="bluebackgroundtop"></div>
        <div class="headercontent">
             <H1> KLEENZONE </H1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML code, too.

Comment: normaly you would do things like that this way: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/42A8M/

Comment: Sorry.. I'm kind of too busy at work to dedicate the time this question deserves to my answer.  All I can do is drop this demo and answer any questions you might have in either chat or the comments here: http://jsfiddle.net/h74Zc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the `.headerContent` inside of the `.bluebackgroundtop` div, and then style like this:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.headercontent {
    height: 150px;
    width: 950px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center; 
}
.bluebackgroundtop {
    height: 150px;
    width: 1920px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color: #3c56a6;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/syZdH/2/)**

Comment: this has almost worked, but there is now a gap at the top of white?

Comment: That's because of the `user agent stylesheet`- which applies automatic margins and paddings. I am using the universal selector to clear it off, though in real life, you should use [reset.css](http://www.cssreset.com/). http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/syZdH/2/

Comment: @user3086732 Does that satisfy the requirements ?

Comment: The browser applies some of its own rules, i.e. it sets `margin`, `padding`, etc. by default. The 'gap at the top of white' was a `margin` applied by the browser. You need to override these styles by using either `*{margin:0;padding:0;}` or the reset css files to which i gave the link above. Hope it helps!